# Nested functions within an object javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, nested, object-literal

I am trying to add an additional function to my object.  I am getting an error of undefined.  I am confused.  I want to be able to enter this line and have the object function execute.

```
var Button = System.Windows.Forms.Control.TabControl();
Button.TabPages.Add();
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
 System.Windows = {};
 System.Windows.Forms={};
 System.Windows.Forms.Control={
    TabControl: function () {
         this.Node;
         var self=this;
         this._ID="id test";
         TabPages= {
             //
             Add: function () {
                 Debug.WriteLine("ADD ID:"+self._ID);
             }
         }
         this.Focus = function () {
             this.Node.focus();
         }
         this.NodeCreate = function () {
             Debug.WriteLine("node created");
             var btn = document.createElement("button");
             btn.type = "button";
             btn.name = this._Name;
             this.Node = btn;
         }
         this.NodeCreate();
     }
 }
```

Somehow I think I am confusing the scopes or something.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: in `System.Windows.Forms.Control.TabControl();`, `Control` doesn't exist. it'S `TabControl` directly after `Forms`.

Comment: That was a typo when I copied and pasted to SO.  Fixed it.  The problem still persists.

Comment: Inside `TabControl`, `this` refers to `System.Window.Forms.Control`, are you aware of that? To make it work like you described, you'd have to `return this;` from the function and you have to assign `TabPages` to `this` as well, not make it a global variable like you are doing now. However, the whole setup still seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs without errors, but doesn't physically add the button to the page because you never added it to the document.  I assume that's the next step.

```
    var System = {
            Windows : {
                Forms : {
                    Control : {
                        TabControl : function ()
                        {
                            var self=this;
                            this.Node = null;
                            this._ID="id test";
                            this.TabPages = {
                                //
                                Add: function () {
                                    console.log("ADD ID:"+self._ID);
                                }
                            };
                            this.Focus = function () {
                                 this.Node.focus();
                            };
                            this.NodeCreate = function () {
                                console.log("node created");
                                var btn = document.createElement("button");
                                btn.type = "button";
                                btn.name = this._Name;
                                self.Node = btn;
                                return self.Node;
                            }
                            self.NodeCreate();
                            return this;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Button = new System.Windows.Forms.Control.TabControl();

    Button.TabPages.Add();
```

Comment: I fixed what you said but I still get the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ".  I think it has to do with either how I am calling the add function or how the add function was created (the nesting and stuff).  But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: *"It's a design issue with Javascript that will likely be fixed in ES6."* no it's not, and hence it won't be fixed. What will be new is that arrow functions will use the same `this` value as the environment they are contained in, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I could have sworn they were going to correct 'this' in inner  functions so that we didn't have to keep supplying the correct context when using apply() and call().

Comment: Where do you create the System object?  There has to be more than you're showing in the initial example, as near as I can see.